# How to replace every text in a Mac folder?

Tags: macos, find-and-replace

In Mac OS, how do I find and replace a certain text in all of a directory and its sub directories?

Comment: file/directory names are contents?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a combination of [`find(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/find.1.html) and [`sed(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html):

```
# Find all files under the directory hierarchy rooted at 'root', and replace
# all instances of the regular expression 'pattern' with 'replacement' in all
# of those files:
find root -type f -exec sed -i~ 's/pattern/replacement/g' '{}' '+'
```

If you run into command line length limitations, replace the `'+'` at the end with `';'`.  This will make it run slower (since it was to fork a new process for each file), but it will not have a danger of too long of a command line for `sed`.

You can also only do the replacement for certain files by adding appropriate filters to `find` (e.g. `-name *.txt` to only replace .txt files).